# Too old to custom-rom?

Tags: rooting, custom-roms, customization

So I got the notion to install cyanogen mod on my old samsung galaxy tab 2 10.1. To speed it up, get it running nougat, and get back into the swing of dabbling with Android software.

The rooting process was simple, but it doesn't seem like I'm able to find what I need in order to get Lineage OS on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 I can't find the proper tools.

Is it possible for a device to simply be too old to flash a custom rom? Or am I missing an important resource?

If anyone could shed some light, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XDA is the de facto "standard" for roms, especially on common devices like this, but it seems they are struggling to bring Nougat to this device in reading some of [these threads](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-2/galaxy-tab-2-unified). I would suggest watching them and in the mean time find a stable Marshmallow ROM, there seems to be several for this device at the same link I mentioned earlier.

It's not about being "too old" per se, but more if the binary blobs and drivers available from the manufacturer can be incorporated into a new ROM and specifically it's kernel. After a while they just become incompatible and unsupported and outside of the realm of developers to effectively adjust the base source to work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll set up an account over there as I continue to dabble.